# How to implement the search for the twitter APIs in controller as well as in Erb template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter-gem

I am new to Ruby on Rails as i want to develop a twitter app with the search option. Using which an user can search for the other users. I am using twitter gem and oauth gem for my project. I Have tried using below given code but its not working though **get_client.search("user")** it working in Rails Console.

```
def get_client
    Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
      config.consumer_key = "ABCD"
      config.consumer_secret = "XYZ"
      config.access_token = "PQRS"
      config.access_token_secret = "LMNO"
   end
end
```

```
def search
  query = (param[:search]) 
  get_client.search("query")
end
```

Comment: How did you attempt to solve this?

Comment: Make a controller action use the twitter gem's `#search` function. Also, attempt the solution yourself.

Comment: I got it was doing wrong **get_client.search** will only give me the tweets. To fetch the user for particular username have to use **get_client.user("username")**
thanx guys